# What exactly is the sobolev-space of $L^1$-valued functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

in a paper about PDEs, they use the *Sobolev space*:

$$W^{1,\infty}(0,T;L^1(0,L)),$$

where $T$ and $L$ are just positive real numbers. I know the concept of Sobolev spaces of functions which are real-valued (and also found something concerning *vector-valued* online), but I really have no idea what this space here is.

I would like to know:

1. What functions belong to this space?
2. How is the norm defined?
3. A source or a proof which states that this is a Banach space.

Thanks!

*(The original paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05408). The above mentioned space appears in the beginning of the proof to theorem 3.1.)*

Comment: [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6A.pdf) seems useful

Comment: @JohnMa thank you. In definition 6.37, the norm is defined, but I don't understand: How can we take the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$ of $\partial_t u$ if this is not an element in $X$, but a function from $(0;T)$ into $X$? And does it really make sense that the eventual norm of $u$ only depends on some norms of the weak derivatives of $u$ ($j \ge 1$ in the formula), but not on some norm of $u$ itself?

Comment: I think that's a typo, it should be $\sum_{j} \int_0^T\| \partial^j_t u\|^p_X dt$ instead, which is the same as  $\sum_{j} \int_0^T\| \partial^j_t u(t)\|^p_X dt$

Answer (score 1):

I think, that we could consider an element from $W^{1,\infty}(0,T;L^1(0,L))$ as a function $u(t,x):(0,T)\times(0,L)\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{W^{1,\infty}(0,T;L^1(0,L))} = \operatorname{esssup}_{(0,T)}\int_0^L|u(t,x)|dx + \operatorname{esssup}_{(0,T)}\int_0^L|\partial_tu(t,x)|dx <\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, in a *Section 1.7* of a book:

*Pascal Cherrier, Albert Milani - Linear and Quasi Linear Evolution Equations in Hilbert Spaces, 2010*

(and a references given there) you should find answers to all of your three questions.

It deals with spaces of this kind.